# about multiple relations in django.models? noob here

Tags: django, django-models

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Leagues(models.Model):
    LeagueName = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Team(models.Model):
    TeamName = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class LeagueTable(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(Leagues)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    matches_played = models.IntegerField()
    matches_won = models.IntegerField()
    matches_drawn = models.IntegerField()
    matches_lost = models.IntegerField()
    points = models.IntegerField()

class FixtureTable(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(Leagues)
    fixture_date = models.DateField('Fixture Date')
    team_one = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    team_one_score = models.IntegerField()
    team_two = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    team_two_score = models.IntegerField()
```

in the "class FixtureTable", i want team_one and team_two to be linked to two differnt teams in "class Team" models. how to create multiple relations, or is it possible.

PS: this is purely a noob, with a little experience in programming, but no experience with either python or databases.

thankyou.

Comment: one more thing, although i am following a tutorial, i found, the best way to learn is, create your own problem, and follow the tutorial while solving your own problem. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many ForeignKeys as you like to the same model. I suspect what's tripping you up is Django giving you an error saying that you need to specify a related name.

By default, Django creates an attribute on the opposite model of the form `<model>_set`. So in the following scenario:

```
class FixtureTable(models.Model):
    team_one = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

Django would add a related manager to `Team` as `fixturetable_set`. If you then did:

```
class FixtureTable(models.Model):
    team_one = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    team_two = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

Django would attempt to add the same attribute *twice* and obviously fail. The fix is to specify a `related_name`, so each can have a unique related manager:

```
class FixtureTable(models.Model):
    team_one = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team_one_fixturetables')
    team_two = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team_two_fixturetables')
```

Then, everything will work fine. You can specify whatever you like for `related_name` as long as it's unique for the model.

Comment: awesome ... this helped me solve my problem .. thanks @Chris Pratt